# Image link, wider than image actually is

Tags: html, css

I have prepared layout of my website's footer and I wanted to do it the way I have imagined, but it turned out that it is not as easy as I thought.

Here is comic book with story about naughty link image that does not want to work properly:

[image: Whole story]

What I want to do with my code:

1. I want to make `<footer>` at the bottom of the page.
2. I fill `<footer>` with three flex boxes (`<div>`), which distribution is 25% - 50% - 25%.
3. Middle `<div>` contains image at the bottom center.
4. Image contained in the middle `<div>` has to be a link via `<a>`.

What I thought my code will do:

- When you click ONLY(!!!) an image you will activate a link.

What my code really does:

- When I hover mouse anywhere in this middle `<div>` area (and this is a bit tricky!!) but ONLY anywhere from the bottom to image height (so ONLY lower half of middle `<div>`). Link is also active at whole width of `<div>` which contains image. Blue area on picture below in link. You can also see this in the snippet.

I have CSS style and HTML codes as follows:

```css
footer {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 100%;
    -moz-box-flex:  1 100%;
    -webkit-flex:  1 100%;
    -ms-flex: 1 100%;
    flex:  1 100%;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:black;
}
footer section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:90%;
    height:200px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background-color:red;
}
.footerLogo{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 25%;
    -moz-box-flex:  1 25%;
    -webkit-flex:  1 25%;
    -ms-flex: 1 25%;
    flex:  1 25%;
    order:1;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.footerGoUp{
    -webkit-box-flex: 2 50%;
    -moz-box-flex:  2 50%;
    -webkit-flex:  2 50%;
    -ms-flex: 2 50%;
    flex:  2 50%;
    order:2;
    align-self:flex-end;
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.footerSocialLogos{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 25%;
    -moz-box-flex:  1 25%;
    -webkit-flex:  1 25%;
    -ms-flex: 1 25%;
    flex:  1 25%;
    order:3;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
div.asImage{
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:green;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
     <section>
         <div class="footerLogo">
         </div>
         <div class="footerGoUp">
             <a href="#top">
                 <div class="asImage">
                 </div>
             </a>
          </div>
          <div class="footerSocialLogos">
          </div>
       </section>
   </footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.asImage { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: But afterwards my .asImage goes to the left side of the parent <div>. How can I center it then in a neat way?

Comment: `.footerGoUp { text-align: center; }`

Comment: Please show more effort answering the question a description and the explanation will be nice not just throw some code...